# Generic interface to avoid casting

Tags: java, generics, interface

I want to have an interface that returns different type of interfaces based on what is requested. To explain the issue I used a car example.

```
public interface ICar{
public ? getCar(String carName);
}

public class Car implements ICar{
public ? getCar(String name){
// Depending on the car name return ICommonCar or IBMW or IAudi...
return new BMW();
Or return new Audi(); 
...
}
```

And different users classes will get the ICar interface where they can invoke getCar(carName). Eg.
First class can request:

```
IBMW mycar = ICar.getCar(BMW);
```

Second class requests:

```
IAudi myCar = ICar.getCar(Audi);
```

I was thinking to use Java Generics to solve the issue but I think there is something that I am missing. My first approach was to something like below:

```
public class Car<T>{ 
public T getCar(String carName){
public T newCar;
if(carName.equals(BMW)){
T = new BMW(); // Shall I cast it T?
}else if(carName.equals(Audi))
T = new Audi();
}...

return T;
}
```

The code above in using Generics doesn't compile but I just put it to show the intention that I want to achieve. The problem seems simple but I found using Generics to be tricky. Is it possible to solve the above problem using Generics? Thank you in advance!

EDIT:

Please consider that in the example I did not meant to imply that IBMW & IAudi as child interfaces of the ICar interface but rather I was thinking to have the ICar as an entry point where different types of checks will be performed on the request & on the class initiating request. Then implementation of unrelated interfaces like IBMW & IAudi which are child interfaces of ICommonCar would be returned. I should have used a different example.

Comment: I think you should explain more what do you want to do, or at least in what case you want to apply this.

Comment: Generics do not at all work the way you expect them here. before I help in answering, I would rather suggest for greater good that you read a tutorial on java generics http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Comment: @TheRedFox. All I want is to have a method that has an anonymous return type. A method that can return eg. IBMW or IAudi dynamically based. If I declare the return type of the method getCar as IBMW I won't be able to return IAudi & vise versa.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve something like you describe, you are going to make the client do as much work as he would do by performing his own cast.  I'm changing your class names to make more sense.  To whit:

```
ICarFactory cf = new CarFactory();
// normal way
IAudi audi = ( IAudi )cf.getCar( "audi" );
// your way
IBMW bmw = cf.getCar( "bmw", IBMW.class );
```

The difference being that in the former case, you need only return `ICar` from `getCar`, whereas in the latter, you need to make the *method* `getCar` generic in a variable `< T extends ICar >` and then cast to `T` before returning your car.  That may not even be legal in all cases.

Meantime you get zero help from the compiler regarding types in either case.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are looking for a factory pattern. I try to avoid using strings to specify what I want the factory to make - enums are a good fit.

```
interface Car {

}

class BMW implements Car {

}

class Audi implements Car {

}

interface MakesCars {

    Car makeCar() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException;
}

enum Cars implements MakesCars {

    BMW(BMW.class),
    Audi(Audi.class);
    Class<? extends Car> c;

    Cars(Class<? extends Car> c) {

    }

    @Override
    public Car makeCar() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        return c.newInstance();
    }

}

public void test() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    Car bmw = Cars.BMW.makeCar();
}
```

The Java 8 version of the enum is a little more elegant.

```
enum Cars implements MakesCars {

    BMW(BMW::new),
    Audi(Audi::new);
    final Supplier<Car> supplier;

    Cars(Supplier<Car> supplier) {
        this.supplier = supplier;
    }

    @Override
    public Car makeCar() {
        return supplier.get();
    }

}
```

Comment: I think the OP wants the return type of `makeCar` to somehow vary with respect to which car factory was called.

Comment: @JudgeMental - That's not how I read the question - perhaps this will become clearer in time.